# Is it appropriate to use 'eagerly' while ending a formal e-mail

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary, formality, email

Nowadays, I always use the following phrase when I am ending formal email;

> I eagerly await for your response.
>
> Regards,

I've seen this phrase somewhere, kind-of a formal e-mail and I am using it since then instead of always saying *I look forward to your response*.

I would like to know if it is suitable to use that phrase for formal email.

Comment: Not what you asked, so this is a comment and not an answer, but "await for" is not quite right.  You "await" or you "wait for", but not "await for".

Comment: Do you really eagerly await a response to every formal email you send?  I know I sure don't.

Comment: @snumpy yes, I do.

Comment: How would 'keenly awaiting your response' compare to 'eagerly awaiting'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It really depends on how eager you wish to seem. If you don't mind coming off a little strong, it's fine. But you could convey nearly the same level of enthusiasm by simply saying "I look forward to hearing from you." That is only if using eagerly would make you seem too desperate.

Comment: All true, but depending on context, "eagerly awaiting" might come across as a somewhat impertinent request for promptness (or even any response at all). For example, if you were emailing a senior politician who mightn't have the time or the inclination to respond to every email he gets.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If I were emailing a senior politician, who works for *me*, I might just expect him to have the inclination, if not the time, to respond to my emails.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this would be acceptable, however I would change it a bit.

> I eagerly await your response.

Comment: @ham ok now you ruin my day with this answer, officially :s tell me that: from 1 to 10, how badly can a person look like if s/he uses this phrase for like a two month inside informal e-mails? 10 is **horrible**, 1 is **not at all**

Comment: Why would you not use this in a formal email?

Comment: Round about 4 actually, 'cos it's likely not many people will actually realise it.

Comment: Because, it's... not formal? I mean, it's just like saying to the queen "Hey, that dress you are wearing is so cool!". It isn't formal. You'd probably have said," Your attire today is very becoming!"

Comment: What's informal about "eagerly"? It's not a slang term.

Comment: It may not be slang, but its..."familiar". When you are formal, nothing familiar is used. That's why I said, it is appropriate for emails to friends, family, informal, etc., but not in formal emails.

Comment: I just don't accept that there's anything familiar about this. What familiar sentiment does it convey? You can very well eagerly await a response from a complete stranger, if there is something to be eager about. If anything, depending on the preceding email it might read as arch, rather than friendly.

Comment: @Marcin, actually, I begin to see your point. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is completely acceptable. I have used "I await your reply eagerly" in formal letters also, although obviously not when I wanted to be snotty.

Comment: @marcin ok now I am confused :s

Comment: Well, it's grammatically incorrect, but the use of "eagerly" is not the problem.

Comment: @Marcin how about **I eagerly await your response** ? Would that be grammaticality correct?

Comment: @tugberk: Yes, although if you want to be even more formal, avoid the split infinitive.

Comment: @Marcin, Split infinitive?

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: There's no infinitive here, I'm just tired. What I meant was: avoid placing your adverb between the verb and the pronoun.

Comment: Ah! I understand. How about a cofee!?

Comment: @Marcin: Are you sure about that? Neither adjective position seems at all informal to me...

Comment: @psmears: I'm sure about it.

Comment: @Marcin: On what evidence do you base that certainty? Usually the difference in adverb position between pre-main-verb and sentence-final is one of emphasis - "I'll happily do that" versus "I'll do that *happily*" - not one of formality. Indeed, in oaths - surely one of the most formal uses there are - forms such as *I solemnly swear* abound.  (The [US presidential oath](http://americanhistory.about.com/od/uspresidents/ss/inauguration_5.htm) uses this form, as does one version of the [UK parliamentary oath of allegiance](http://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/swearingin/).)

Comment: @psmears: An emphatic sign-off lends an air of weight.